# Multi Criteria Dsum

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Im starting to pull my hair out.

I am looking to do a multi criteria dsum that looks at the current user and todays date.

Tried many variations but must be missing something very simple so any help is appreciated

```
StatusBox = DSum("[Task_time]", "[tbl_Data]", "[CDP] = '" & Environ("username") & "' and [Record_Date] = '" & Date & "'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates must be enclosed with `#`. Also they need to be formatted in order to return the desired result.

Try this:

```
StatusBox = DSum("[Task_time]", "[tbl_Data]", "[CDP] = '" & Environ("username") & "' and [Record_Date] = #" & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just making it slightly too complicated:

```
StatusBox = DSum("[Task_time]", "[tbl_Data]", "[CDP] = '" & Environ("username") & "' And [Record_Date] = Date()")
```